# How can I enable retries for google cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I created google cloud function:

```
@scheduler_fn.on_schedule(
    schedule="00 06 1 * *",
)
def getRates(event: scheduler_fn.ScheduledEvent) -> None:
    asyncio.run(getRatesAsync())
```

How can I enable retry for this function?

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries - I tried to configure from the GCP Console. This document tells to press 'Edit' icon in Eventarc trigger pane and edit your trigger's settings.

I actually see this:

[image]

I tried to press Edit icon and see this:

[image]

I don't understand - how can I edit trigger settings here?

Then I tried to configure retries from function code. According to the guide - I need to call `functions.runWith({failurePolicy: true}).foo.onBar(myHandler);` for this.

Now I just run `firebase deploy -- only functions` from firebase CLI and the function works.

I don't understand - where should I add `runWith` here.

I work with Flutter from VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct way to configure retries using the google.cloud.scheduler_v1 package itself. Instead, you can use the google.cloud.functions package to deploy your function and specify the retry configuration.

```
from google.cloud import functions_v1

client = functions_v1.CloudFunctionsServiceClient()

location = "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/YOUR_REGION"
function_name = "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/YOUR_REGION/functions/YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME"

retry = {
    "retryConfig": {
        "retryCount": 3,  
        "maxRetryDuration": "600s"  
    }
}

deployment = functions_v1.CloudFunction(location=location, retry=retry)

operation = client.update_function(name=function_name, function=deployment)
operation.result()
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.functions_v1' has no attribute 'CloudFunctionsServiceClient'